# Как распарсить данные из json

Tags: javascript, json_encode

Есть данные, которые приходят из пхп по json. 
'$.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){
    var str = Arr;'
Вид у них ["583","583","580","584.. как я понимаю это строка. Нужно привести к виду массива.
затем использую 'str = str.replace(/"(?=[^[]*])/g, '');' НО в конце и в начале остаются [] (квадратные скобки, ну не режет он их и все).
Затем использую 'str = str.substr(1);' (отрезает первую скобку). 
'//str = (0, str.length - 1);' - НЕ работает, удаляет ВСЮ строку, а не последний элемент.
потом склеиваю 'str = str.split(',');'
в результате (без обрезания последнего знака) получается массив вида 583,583,580,584,58....9,577,577,579,485,485] - НО как и говорил, в конце квадратные скобки
Спустя некое время нашел такой код(отрезает последний символ) - но он ужасен.

> 'var str = Arr,z;  str =
> str.replace(/[\S\s]$/, function(f) { z
> = f; return ""}); В результате
>       $.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){ 
>       var str = Arr,z;
>       str = str.substr(1);
>       str = str.replace(/"(?=[^[]*])/g, '');
>       str = str.replace(/[\S\s]$/, function(f) { z = f; return ""});
>       str = str.split(',');
>       document.write(str);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse() , или в jQuery просто `$.get('url',function(Arr){},"json");`

информация к размышлению из вики:

> JSON (англ. **JavaScript** Object Notation)

Comment: да да JSON.parse(Arr); то что нужно. Еще след вопрос $.get('url',function(Arr){},"json"); работать с данными можно только внутри {}, можно ли передать значения в другую функцию ?

Comment: @anunak, можно передать через видимые (для функции) переменные. Например, есть глобальный объект `app`, который сохраняет историю вызовов:
```
App = function(){
    var ajaxStack = [];
    this.pushAjaxResult = function(ajaxResult)
    {
        ajaxStack.push(ajaxResult);
    }
    this.getLastAjaxResult = function()
    {
        return ajaxStack[ajaxStack.length - 1];
    }
};
app = new App(); // теперь window.app будет ссылаться на инстанс App
```
После этого можно делать так:
```
$.get('url',function(data){
    app.pushAjaxResult(data);
},"json");
```
cont ->

Comment: После этого можно делать так:

    $.get('url',function(data){
        app.pushAjaxResult(data);
    },"json");

И даже так (**но этого ни в коем случае делать не надо**)

    $.get('url',function(data){
        app.data = data;
    },"json");

Однако, **передача данных на самом деле нужна крайне редко**. Обычно "снаружи" функции создаются необходимые обработчики, а внутри функции-коллбека они вызываются.

   app.populateTable = function(data) {/* какой-то код, который выводит данные */}
    $.get('url',function(data){
        app.populateTable(data);
    },"json");

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вот есть такой код js

    '$(function () {
    var sin = [], cos = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
    sin.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
    cos.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);
    }
    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
    [ { data: sin, label: "sin(x)"}, { data: cos, label: "cos(x)" } ],     {....</pre>
как я понимаю знак $ делает переменные видимыми для других функций?

Comment: @anunak нет - $ здесь, это ссылка на объект jQuery. в js $ - незарезервированный  символ. в вашем примере оно используется как сокращение от

    $(document).ready(function(){});

т.е. 

    $(function() {}); 

тоже самое.

вообще хорошая практика делать так:

    jQuery(function($){}); //это тоже самое, 

только теперь  последующие переопределение jQuery или $ не повлияет на выполнение кода

Comment: объединяя все выше сказанное получим 
App = function(){
    var ajaxStack = [];
    this.pushAjaxResult = function(ajaxResult)
    {
        ajaxStack.push(ajaxResult);
    }
    this.getLastAjaxResult = function()
    {
        return ajaxStack[ajaxStack.length - 1];
    }
};
app = new App();
 $.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){
 app.pushAjaxResult(Arr);
},"json")
Но как мне вызвать в функции вот этот app
$(function () {
  //?
});

Comment: неправильно, вам не нужен этот стэк, если вы хотите отрисовать график используя какую-то js функцию, вы можете воспользоваться событиями или передать значение через переменную в общей для рисовальщика графика и ajax запроса области видимости. К сожалению вам придется выучить javascript для этого. Т.к. методом тыка эта задача не решается.

Comment: Все что мне нужно - это передать массив, который лежит в $.get в функцию '$(function () { var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];...'
т.е. задача примитивная, я не думаю что нужны какие то сложные пути
все просто - как и говорил Fike

 $.get('/testo.php',function(Arr){
 var x = JSON.parse(Arr);
 app.populateTable(x);
},"json")

app.populateTable = function(x) {alert(x)
var buf =[];
for (var i = 0;i<x.length;i++){
 buf[i]=[i,x[i]];
}

Comment: да, это не сложно, это просто основы js, вот пример того о чем я говорил. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7zYDv/